# MAC OSX and FreeIPA integration?

Tags: mac-osx, freeipa

There seem to be just one Documentation in FreeIPA and that also says to use weak crypto ciphers and does not seem to support the --mkhomedir option since there is no IPA-Client for MAC OSX 10

Anyone has any idea if MACOSX 10 works properly with Free IPA ?